# How to 'Ignore' a Method using Python-Mockito?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mockito

I am new to unit testing and the mockito library, and am trying to figure out how to 'skip' or 'ignore' a class instantiation within a method call. I have some code that looks like this:

```
def main(args):
  ...
  ...
  notify = Notify(some_variables)
  ...
  try:
    ...
    ...
  except Exceptions as err:
    notify.alert(some_variables)
```

I tried mocking this method like:

```
notice_mock = mock()
when(notify).Notify(some_variables).thenReturn(notice_mock)
```

However, it still instantiated the class and is throwing errors because of other method calls in that class. Am I misunderstanding the function of mock()? Is there a way to ignore this method?

Answer (score 0):

That's a question about "where" to mock.  The code under test uses `Notify(...)` within `def main`.  Assume, you may have this in a file `foo.py`.

During the test you essentially mock `notify.Notify(...)` (`when(<object/container>).<name/member>(...)`) but the code under test *uses* `foo.Notify`.

You may have a `import foo as system_under_test` line in the test file or something similar.  Then a `when(system_under_test).Notify(...)` should do the patch.